# Linkify Method in html.erb file showing up with HTML in view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, linkify

sorry if this is a noob question but im calling the following method on the @page instance variable, and the view is populating with html tags...

```
module PagesHelper
  def linkify_page page
    regex = /\[\[([^|]+)\|(\w+)\]\]/
    page.text.gsub(regex) do |link|
      caps = regex.match(link)
      linked_page = page.adventure.pages.where(:name => caps[2]).first
      link_to(caps[1], adventure_page_path(page.adventure_id, linked_page.id))
    end
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= linkify_page(@page) %>
```

Result in the view...

```
I can't wait to <a href="/adventures/1/pages/2">see the end</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `html_safe` to escape the `HTML` tags

```
<%= linkify_page(@page).html_safe %>
```

**OR**

use `raw`

```
<%= raw linkify_page(@page) %>
```

**OR**

Just use `<%==` which is equivalent of `raw`

```
<%== linkify_page(@page) %>
```

For more details,see these [**Guides**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#output-safety)

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw` or `html_safe`

raw

```
<%= raw linkify_page(@page) %>
```

html_safe

```
<%= linkify_page(@page).html_safe %>
```